# Integer arithmetic performance 32 vs. 64-bit

Tags: performance, f#

I have 2 machines running F# 2.0 Interactive build 4.0.30319.1 on vs 2010. Several of my programs ran significantly slower on the faster machine. The problem appears to be that integer arithmetic performance on a 32-bit Windows is significantly slower than 64 Windows.

On the slightly slower Windows 7 64-bit machine  (the program is listed below):

> primeCount = 1270607
>   Real: 00:00:07.553, CPU: 00:00:07.519, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0

On the slightly faster Windows XP SP2 machine :

> primeCount = 1270607
>   Real: 00:00:32.800, CPU: 00:00:32.796, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0

So the 32-bit version takes more than 4 times as long as the 64-bit version.  I am assuming that there is not a significant difference due to the different operating systems, othen than the word length that is supported.

Program:

```
let isPrime(n) =
    if n < 2 then false
    elif (n % 2) = 0 then                   // take care of even case
        if n = 2 then true
        else false
    else                                    // n is odd
        let ms = int(sqrt(float(n)))
        let rec isPrimeUtil(m) =
            if m > ms then true
            elif n % m = 0 then false
            else isPrimeUtil(m + 2)
        isPrimeUtil(3)

let nums = [1 .. 20000000]
let pcountref = ref 0                       // # of primes found

let primeCount =
    pcountref := 0
    for x in nums do
        if (isPrime x) then incr pcountref

do primeCount
printfn "primeCount = %d" !pcountref
```

Send the program to interactive. `#time;;` Then to measure the elapsed time for processing, and not the generation of the range nums, select the line

```
let pcountref = ref 0
```

and all subsequent lines and send to interactive.

Comment: Where does `BigInteger` come in? The code you've shown certainly doesn't use it...

Comment: oops!  you are correct.  The issue seems to be 64 vs 32 bit arithmetic.

Comment: @DougT - int is 32 bits on 32 bit and 64 bit

Comment: FSI is 32 bit, so you're running 32bit versions on both your machines. Check `System.IntPtr.Size*8` in FSI on the 64 bit machine. I'm pretty sure the answer will be **32**.

Comment: > System.IntPtr.Size*8;;
val it : int = 32

Comment: clarification:  The machine that runs Windows XP SP2 is a 64 bit machine, but the version of Windows XP is a 32 bit version.

Answer (score 3):

I think the more likely explanation is that the 64 bit JIT performs tail call optimizations which the 32 bit JIT does not.  THe `isPrimeUtil` function could be optimised

Note that the given example doesn't use BigInteger anyway, there is also room for algorithmic improvements - a sieve will run much faster

Comment: 32-bit JIT does perfom tailcall optimization according to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davbr/archive/2007/06/20/tail-call-jit-conditions.aspx - maybe one of the conditions is not met?

Comment: @ssg - The F# compiler itself will optimize away the recursive calls to `isPrimeUtil` (basically turning it into a loop).  However, it will not generate a `.tail` prefix for the call to `isPrimeUtil` from `isPrime`, because even though this is a tail call, it is statically known that this call will only add a single stack frame.  I believe in these circumstances the 64-bit JIT might treat it as a tail call anyway, while the 32-bit JIT won't.  However, I'm not sure that this single call would account for the performance difference.

Comment: I converted isPrimeUtil to a while loop, removing the recursion.  The time on 64 bit Windows was 8.3 seconds and on 32 bit Windows was 36.7 seconds, so the ratio remained about the same.  So it is still not clear to me why there is such a big difference.

Answer (score 1):

`float` is 64 bit, so the `sqrt(float(n))` call is probably your performance sink. (And would explain why the 64 bit machine handles it much better.)

Try float32 if you don't need / the precision.

See : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233210.aspx

I don't have a 32 bit machine to test, but on my 64 bit machine just testing the sqrt code takes a reasonable chunk of time.

```
let nums = [1 .. 20000000]

let ans = List.map (fun n -> int(sqrt(float(n))) nums
```

Gives a real time of 5.120s - which is a significant chunk of your execution time.

Comment: native floats are 64 bits on both 64 and 32 bit machines + `sqrt(float(n))` is not even in the inner loop so this is almost certainly incorrect

Comment: the fact they're 64 bits on both machines was precisely my point (i.e. a 64 bit machine can perform maths on a 64 bit float faster than a 32 bit machine).

Comment: @John : `int(sqrt(float(n)))` is called once per odd `n` of `isPrime(n)` -- that's not insignificant.

Comment: changing float to float32 does not change the run time.

Comment: In the above code, let nums = ...  takes most of the time.  My timing did not include the generation of nums (see original post).  The timing for let ans = ...  was about 2+ seconds on both machines.

Comment: @ildjarn - compare once per odd `n` to `Sqrt(n)` per odd n divisions - from this www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf, DIV is 42 cycles for 32 bits and float sqrt is 70.  THe two are about the same but you do many more divisions

Comment: @Massif - source? - float registers are in fact 80 bits on both machines, and all float calculations are done at 80 bits of precision and only truncated down to 64 bits when stored in main memory.  There is no reason why 64 bit should be faster unless you are using SSE instructions (some of which are not available on 32 bit CPUs), which I doubt is happening.

Comment: I have been exposing my deep ignorance of the x86 architecture in assuming the register size differed between the 32bit and 64bit architectures. I bow to your superior knowledge...

Answer (score 0):

These results make sense.  BigNum implementations often use a machine integer until they detect overflow, and then switch to a more complex representation.  64-bit integers can hold much larger values than 32-bit integers.  Your test program is probably spending much more of the test doing fast machine arithmetic when it's running on 64-bit.

Comment: There is no `BigNum` used here, merely `int`.

Comment: He uses `int` with big ranges, not any `BigInteger` in his implementation.

Comment: I didn't even look at the code; I just assumed he was telling the truth when he asked about BigInteger!

Comment: See my previous comment.  BigInteger is not the issue (since it is not used).  All of the arithmetic was  in range of int32.  So the difference appears to be 32 vs 64 bit arithmetic, even though all values fit in an int32.